# [] pointers operations in c

Tags: c, pointers, operator-precedence

```
int x[4] = {12, 20, 39, 43}, *y;        y = x;  Assume each expression is evaluated after the previous one (take all previous ones in consideration)
*y + 1
*(y + 1) y += 2; 
*y = 38
*y - 1
*y++
*y  
y[0]   [Hint: y is not pointing to x[0] anymore so think about it and search for what it means]
```

Here the question i'm trying to solve

1: what does y[0] means ?

I searched online and find nothing !

2:(*y-1) is the operation evaluated left to right ? is y going to point on the element before the one it points at it now?

thank you

Comment: For a pointer `T* p`, `p[N]` is defined as `*(p + N)`. That's it.

Comment: Which of the sentences, in your opinion, change(s) `y`?

Comment: Could you edit your code and make it... legal? Right now what you wrote won't compile.

Comment: Arrays can decay to pointers and both arrays and pointers can use the [] operator and the dereference operator.

Comment: What do you mean you searched online and didn't find anything? There's literally a wikipedia page about pointers (check the C section): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)

Comment: you can answer yourself all questions by just using `printf("*y + 1 = %i\n", *y + 1);` and so on

Comment: I meant for the [] to be used with pointer :) btw thanks @DeiDei

Comment: Read: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence 
*y - 1 means subtract 1 from the element at y.  Whereas y-1 means move the pointer back one.  And please post valid code.  As it stands this snippet of code will not compile.

Comment: You seem to be missing some semicolons in your text, which completely changes the meaning and renders much of it invalid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer is an address in memory.

If you have an `int*`, it is the address of an int.

Now you have two differents way to access to the value at this address.

```
int a = 1;
int *ptr = &a; // ptr is the address of a

printf("%d\n", *ptr); // should print "1" because *ptr is the content at the address stored in ptr
```

Now when we work with array, this syntax is not easy to to read, so there is another syntax which is:

```
int array[4] = { 21, 42, 84, 64 };
// Here array is also an address, the address of the first element

printf("%d\n", array[1]); // this should print "42"
```

In fact when you use the array syntax `aka array[1]`, it is exactly as if you were doing `*(array + 1)`.

It is also why the first element of an array is [0], because it's like if you were doing `*(array + 0)`.

So when you have a pointer (or an array, it's the same), `*ptr == ptr[0]`.

I will put every answer to your question with an example:

```
int x[4] = {12, 20, 39, 43}, *y;
y = x;
*y + 1; // 13
*(y + 1); // 20 (same as y[1])
y += 2; // y is now the address of 39
*y = 38; // { 38, 43 }
*y - 1; // 37
*y++; // 43 (y++ then *y)
*y; // 43
y[0]; // 43
```

The '*' operator applies on the whole block on his right.
`*y + 1 is like y[0] + 1`
and
`*(y + 1)` is like y[1]`

When you increment a pointer (by doing `ptr += 2` or `ptr++`), the address is in fact incremented by the size of the element.

```
int y = 42;
int *ptr = &y;

ptr += 2; // ptr is now 8 bytes (2 * syzeof(int)) further &y
```

**EDIT:** If you want more details on the operator priorities, you can also look at this link. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Well first thank you for the detailed answer, but there is one thing I didn't get  *y++; // { 39, 43 } here does y point at 39 or 43 ? isn't suppose to increment the pointer y?

Comment: The last example you show, causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Let's go through this step-by-step:

```
int x[4] = {12, 20, 39, 43}, *y;
```

This declares and initializes an array of 4 integer values for x. It also declares y and reserves space to store the address of y.

```
y = x;
```

What is occurring here is that the array x has decayed to a pointer pointing to the address of the first element of x; in code:

```
y = &(x[0]);
```

Next:

```
*y + 1;
```

This expression is a form of pointer arithmetic and is evaluated **right to left**; first, it adds 1 to y (y now points to x[1]) then it dereferences y. Note that at the end of execution of the statement, y's original value is restored: the value was never stored. (It would be different with the increment operators.)

The next expression is functionally the same (but a lot clearer).

```
y += 2;
```

This advances y by 2 offsets; it is the equivalent of writing the following: (y now points to the address of x[2])

```
y = y[2];
```

Next:

```
*y = 38;
```

y is currently pointing to the address x[2]. The value of x[2] is overwritten because we dereferenced a pointer to that address and assigned it a new value. x[2] now equals 38 instead of 39.

```
*y - 1;
```

Again, right to left pointer arithmetic; the returned value is the address of x[1] but the value is lost as it was not stored anywhere.

```
*y++;
```

y now points to x[3]. The function dereferences the value stored at x[2] (note that y is assigned AFTER the expression finishes executing) but that value isn't used.

```
*y;
```

This just dereferences y but doesn't do anything by itself.

```
y[0];
```

Functionally equivalent to the previous statement; it yields the result stored in x[3];

Comment: Thank you .Your answer helped me understand .